# Caching works too good

Tags: php, html, caching, browser

I've a problem (what a coincidence) with my website. My website is build with WordPress. To manage logins and all the stuff I'm using Ultimate Member as plugin and rebuild it. To make my website faster and enable caching, I've installed Cache Enabler.

When I login now into my website, I've the problem that when I switch for example from the account page to an other page, the other page don't knows that the user is already logined and shows an error on the page. When I press no Strg + F5 (which clears the cache and reloads the page), the content is visible.

So is there any way to clear the browsers cache after the login within PHP?